# How does Javascript store information inside of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
    var a={},
    b={key:'b'},
    c={key:'c'};
    
    
    
    a[b]=123;
    a[c]=456;
    
    alert(a[b]);
```

What is the output? Is it 123? 456? Or will it not work?

Comment: You can simply post your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and verify your self

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any arrays.  `a`, `b` and `c` are all objects.

Comment: Edited your question to contain the answer ;)

Comment: Your code is creating an object hash entry using an object as its key. Why you would do this I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any arrays there. Only objects and strings.

Property names (in square bracket notation) are strings, so the objects get coerced into strings.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
a['[Object object]']=123;
a['[Object object]']=456;
console.log(a['[Object object]']);
```

So the output will be `456`.

Comment: I love it when people understand the question even when the OP doesn't know how to ask it.